# (Javascript/CSS) resizing function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, width

I have a container div that has to fit in two different types of pictures. Some pictures are 'potrait', width:533px and height:801px, others are 'landscape', width:800px and height:533px.
So to make the div size change to accommodate for the pictures, I wrote the function described below (the 'photos' var is an array of pictures and the [i] is a variable for changing through them and 'img' is a var that fetches the #container element)

```
function resize() {
        var width = photos[i].clientWidth;
        var height = photos[i].clientHeight;
        if (width + height === 1333) {
            img.style.width="800px";
            img.style.height="533px";
        }
        else if (width + height === 1334) {
            img.style.width="533px"; 
            img.style.height="801px";
            }
        }
```

Then, I placed this function in the next and back functions for switching between the pictures,

```
function next() {
        img.src = photos[i];
        el.innerHTML = caption[i];
        resize();
        if (i<photos.length-1){
     i=i+1;
    } else {
     i=0;
    }    
    }
```

The next and back functions work, but when they get to the pictures that needed to be resized, the container holds the same dimensions that were preset in the CSS.(the preset widht/height in the CSS is for the landscape pictures, because I only have 2 potrait pictures that the div needs to change its size to.

```
#container {
    height: 533px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow:hidden;
```

}

I tried looking at other resize threads but whereas people have needed a way to get only a dynamic width or height, I need both to be that way. I think the problem lies in the "clientWidth/Height" property  which I thought gets the width/height of the object before the '.' And i'm not sure if I should set the CSS container div to have a height or leave it to "auto" or a certain percentage. I'd appreciate any help on the matter :)